# Why does Fabric throw 'TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method'?

Tags: ssh, fabric, ssh-keys

When running a Fabric task on a remote server I get the following stack trace:

```
[x.x.x.x] run: git fetch && git reset --hard origin/develop
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/deploy/workspace/.pyenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/agent.py", line 115, in run
    self._communicate()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/deploy/workspace/.pyenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/agent.py", line 125, in _communicate
    events = select([self._agent._conn, self.__inr], [], [], 0.5)
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

The fact that the Fabric task is trying to perform a *git fetch* and that exceptions is raised in *ssh/agent.py* makes me think something is wrong with SSH authentication.

The same user can run *git fetch* outside of Fabric, and the task runs fine on my laptop.

What's going on here? How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[An issue](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/642) raised on Fabric's issue tracker mentions that the error might arise from not having ssh-agent running on the host.

I solved the problem by starting an ssh-agent and adding the user's key:

```
$> eval `ssh-agent`
$> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Success!

Answer (score 0):

To auto-start ssh-agent when you first login, add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ ! -S ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ]; then
  eval `ssh-agent`
  ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
  ssh-add
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error while using Fabric with Python/Django when I was trying to execute tasks by hand within `./manage.py shell_plus`.

It turns out (for me) that the error was caused by the fact that my shell_plus was set up to use bpython instead of ipython.

When I ran `./manage.py shell_plus --ipython` instead, everything worked perfectly.

I realize that this probably wasn't a direct answer to your problem, but I figure I might as well leave a note here for anyone else who happens across the issue like I did.